# OOP: Having the "action" logic for an "entity" in one class but calling it in another?

Tags: c#, oop, artificial-intelligence

Setting up an AI structure I hit an immediate issue in my interfacing, sorry about the mediocre comments:

```
//Probability is just a class I've made to represent (you guessed it) probability

public interface IAction
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Returns a Dictionary of possible future states of the IEntity parameter and their estimated probability
    /// </summary>
    Dictionary<IEntity, Probability> EstimatePossibleOutcomeSpectrum(IEntity entity);
    /// <summary>
    /// Have the IEntity parameter "do" this action
    /// </summary>
    void Do(IEntity entity);
}

public interface IEntity
{
}
```

The issue is that common sense dictates that an Entity does Actions, not the other way around, obviously I can rename the method so it makes grammatical sense but ultimately I'd like to move "Do" into IEntity, but then when it comes to implementing the interfaces I have no clue how to have the "Entity" do the "Action" without simply "passing the baton" by having something like:

```
public class EntityExample
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Returns a Dictionary of estimated future states after "doing" the IAction parameter
    /// </summary>
    Dictionary<IEntity, Probability> EstimatePossibleOutcomeSpectrum(IAction action)
    {
        action.[Some method or a Action<Entity> call](this);
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// "do" the Action paramater
    /// </summary>
    void Do(IAction action)
    {
        action.[Some method or a Action<Entity> call](this);
    }
}
```

Which feels the same if not worse.

What is best coding practice for something like this? I admit my initial approach is functionally fine, but this feels half as bad as using gotos.

Answer (score 7):

> The issue is that common sense dictates that an Entity does Actions, not the other way around,

Since I don't know what "entities" are, my common sense tells me nothing about whether entities do actions, or whether actions consume entities.

Both "entity" and "action" are nouns in this situation, so I see no reason why they ought not to both be classes.

> What is best coding practice for something like this? I admit my initial approach is functionally fine, but this feels half as bad as using gotos.

Don't worry about what is the most "pure OOP" solution, particularly if it means making weird, inelegant or inefficient code. The belief that OOP is an end in itself even when it makes coding more expensive and difficult I call "object happiness disease".  Writing OOP code should not make you happy; using OOP effectively to lower your costs and improve your quality should make you happy. If OOP isn't the right tool and functional programming is, use functional programming.

Instead, worry about *how you expect the code to look from the caller side*.  An API is a machine that gets used by other developers, so make sure that your API is designed with *their* thoughts and feelings and needs and wants at the forefront of your mind, not with what's "most OOP".  **What kind of code would you like your callers to write**?  Start with that, always.

---

Speaking of functional programming, an approach which you might consider is to go full on functional and represent discrete probability distributions as a monad.

Think of some other monads.  An `IEnumerable<T>` is just a sequence, possibly empty, of T. A `Nullable<T>` is logically the same as a sequence, restricted to exactly one or zero elements. An `IObservable<T>` is a sequence of T that is pushed at you rather than pulled from.  A `Task<T>` is logically an observable that has exactly one value.

Not every monad is logically a sequence, but *probability distributions* are.  A probability distribution, `Distribution<T>` is *an infinite random sequence of T whose outputs conform to a particular distribution*.

If you go this route you'll find that a great many operations fall out naturally from sequence operators.  Conditioned distributions (like "roll two dice but discard the doubles") are just `Where`. P(A|B) (probability of A given B)  is `Func<B, Probability<A>>`, which means that *we can apply the monadic bind operator to conditional probabilities* to chain conditional probabilities together, and thereby *Baysian inference becomes straightforward*. And so on. It's a simple but extremely powerful technique.

Try writing a few implementations of

```
interface IDistribution<T> 
{
  T Sample();
  IDistribution<U> Bind<U>(Func<T, IDistribution<U>> f);
  // f is probability of U given a T
}
```

and see where that gets you.

Comment: As for the definition of entity, sorry I didn't make it clear, both classes match the English words they are named after, an Entity is just as google puts it "a thing with distinct and independent existence."

I can't really mark this as the correct answer I'm afraid, simply telling me I should accept less "bloated" code over more "bloated" but OOP pure code aren't the only two choices, I'm asking for the "good" OOP pure solution that may exist, as given in my example solution I am aware and made you aware that wrapping to make an appearance of OOP pureness is a worse option.

Comment: And as you put it, "What kind of code would you like your callers to write?" that's exactly the problem. A caller would expect to have an entity and an action and they'd call entityExample.Do(actionExample), which is why I made the post.
I appreciate you trying to help with my probability handling but you've made an incorrect assumption of what it is modelling, and that method cannot be applied to what it is. What it is if you're curious is along the lines of if you "go fishing" as an action maybe there's a chance you get injured, a chance you catch a big fish, or a small fish, etc.

Comment: Talking of how you expect the code to look from the caller side: "By the time the code was in reasonable shape -- not yet seriously tested, but usable and compliant with the spec -- we'd been having meetings with the WPF team. [...] Unfortunately, after taking a deep look at their real-world scenarios, we came to the disappointing conclusion that we had designed the wrong thing; this was not actually a feature that would solve their problems." (From [Why No Extension Properties?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/10/05/why-no-extension-properties/)).

Comment: @Shefeto: Right, so what you're describing is a *conditional distribution*, which can be modeled as `Func<Action, Distribution<Outcome>>`.  If you do a monadic bind onto a `Distribution<Action>` then you can answer the question "given a distribution of possible actions, what is the distribution of possible outcomes"?  My point, which I think you have missed, is that *you have an opportunity to more clearly and generally represent the concepts needed for probabilistic reasoning*.  I'm encouraging you to explore that opportunity rather than rejecting it out of hand.

Comment: @Shefeto: **Neither entities nor actions should be doing probabilistic reasoning at all**. You say that an entity is "a thing with independent existence".  OK, my toaster is a thing with independent existence, and **I have never asked my toaster to compute the probability of a shock given the action of me sticking a knife into it**.  Nor have I ever asked that question of any of my knives, nor have I asked that question of the "action" of sticking one thing into another.  If you want to model conditional probability distributions then *write a class for that*.

Comment: @Shefeto: Actions and Entities should contain the minimum information necessary to model their "independent existence" and their behaviour on entities.  They shouldn't have any probabilistic reasoning in them at all; **that is not their concern**.

Comment: @Shefeto: So take a step back and ask yourself not just "how do my callers want to use this thing?" but also *what are the **algebraic** operations in my domain?* Things can become much more clear when you have a complete and understandable diagram of the data flows represented as functions. You'll find that you need to *somehow* represent `Func<Action, Entity, Distribution<Outcome>>`. This gives us the insight that *we have a double-dispatch problem* since both actions and entities can vary. Now you can start to think about different OOP ways to solve double dispatch.

Comment: @Shefeto: Because that's the fundamental cause of your entirely reasonable anxiety about the design of your classes. **Double dispatch problems are served poorly by OOP languages that support single dispatch.** The standard GOF solution is the visitor pattern; study it for inspiration.  You might also want to read my series of articles called "Wizards and Warriors" as it goes into some detail on using the visitor pattern for this sort of problem.

Comment: "given a distribution of possible actions, what is the distribution of possible outcomes"? You are still misunderstanding, it's a single action, multiple possible outcomes. And for the record, yes, a toaster is an entity, if you try and get it to calculate anything it will return an empty dictionary because it lacks a "mind", but it still implements the interface.
The entity SHOULD be doing the reasoning, the function doesn't calculate the ACTUAL outcomes and their odds, just that instance's prediction of them, so a toaster would produce nothing, a goblin would produce a few inaccurately etc.

Comment: I don't see why you're making incorrect assumptions on what the functions do, you know what my question is and yet you've gone a completely unrelated tangent on modelling a different kind of probability than I am modelling, and even after I explained that it's not what you think it is you continue to go by your original interpretation. You are an entity, you calculate outcomes all the time, if someone invites you to sky diving you probably think about the odds of dying or having fun or being too scared to jump etc, that's what this is, no need to over complicate it.

Comment: @Shefeto: I find it interesting that you asked for advice, got advice from someone who *designs probabilistic programming languages for a living*, and have done nothing but push back against it. If you didn't want advice from a professional then you shouldn't have asked for it.

Comment: So in that example the "action" is skydiving, you calculate the possible outcomes and their chances, another method of IEntity would then turn that distribution of outcomes into a score, the better the score the higher priority that Action becomes to execute, if it's what the Entity decides to do then it'd ideally call Do(skydiving)

Comment: I didn't ask advice on probability though? If you went into a mechanic's to get your car fixed and he starts telling you how to vote, you "push back" and he tells you he has studied politics at a PhD level, that doesn't mean it's okay.
And even if it was, you are literally telling me how to write probability for something else, you said an Entity shouldn't do probability reasoning, I can plainly tell that is false because humans do risk assessment constantly! Please explain how that ISN'T exactly what you told me is wrong?

Comment: that last part isn't rhetorical btw, to quote you:

"Neither entities nor actions should be doing probabilistic reasoning at all."

Yet humans (and to a more simplified extent all sentient entities) do it constantly (I already explained that non-sentient entities simply return an empty dictionary), this is inconsistent, please explain since you're the expert apparenty.

Comment: @Shefeto: Let's go through it again, incorporating your notion that entities determine distributions. You say that an entity can determine a probability of taking an action from an action.  That means that an entity is logically `Func<Action, Distribution<Action>>` Which means that *we can apply a monadic bind operation to extend one distribution of actions to another*. Suppose `f` is of type `Func<Entity, Func<Action, Distribution<Action>>` and is `e=>a=>e.Estimate(a)` and we have a prior `Distribution<Action>` called `d` and an Entity `e`. The result you want is simply `d.Bind(f(e))` !

Comment: You see how powerful this is now?  *Any* probabilistic reasoning can be expressed by simply binding onto that monad.  You have a probability of outcomes given an action, say `o` of type `Func<Action, Distribution<Outcome>>` and now you want to know the probability of a certain outcome given an entity and an action prior? It's `d.Bind(f(e)).Bind(o)` ! And now you can `Sample` outcomes given a prior `d`, and an entity `e`, and a probabilistic estimate of outcomes `o`.  Getting all that math right is hard; make `Bind` do it for you.

Comment: Now, where things get a little tricky is when the probability of outcomes *depends on the entity as well as the action*.  But think about it the same way you would think about the same problem in `IEnumerable`:  we have `from x in xs from y in ys(x) select f(x, y)`; **how do we get the `x` into `f(x, y)`** if what we have available is only `Bind(X=>IEnumerable<Y>)`?  Study the implementation of `SelectMany` in LINQ and you will see how it is done.  A similar variation on `Bind` is possible for the probability monad.

Comment: Ok, now I see why we're not getting along, you simply misread the code: "You say that an entity can determine a probability of taking an action from an action." The method if you go look again returns a Dictionary<IEntity, Probability>, the key is of IEntity, it is estimating SOME of the infinite future states it could be in after making the action. And I'm not as much of an expert of probability on you but I'm sure since they are not mutually exclusive that I cannot possibly have a "simple but powerful technique" that says chance of (getting mauled by a bear) | (Caught a fish)

Comment: *Mutually exclusive" was the wrong word, my bad, I just meant dependant, and I know that doesn't on it's own stop you being able to do A given B stuff, however, the method is returning states of IEntity, the state doesn't have written on it "mauled by a bear" and "caught fish", all it has is stuff like health, inventory, energy, and they are mostly continuous, even the inventory will have some continuous values.

Comment: @Shefeto: You're getting hung up on the specifics. My points is that if you design objects that represent a monadic workflow, **they work with any workflow you choose** so you don't *need* to get hung up on the specifics. Let's look at an example. Suppose now we have `f` as `Func<Entity, Func<Action, Distribution<Entity>>>`. Now suppose each entity is given *opportunities* to take actions that are also probabilistic and depend on the entity, so we have `g` = `Func<Entity, Distribution<Action>>`. Now suppose we have a question: what is a likely state of an entity after two opportunities?

Comment: We let `h=e=>g(e).Bind(f(e))` and the function we want is `j=e=>(h(e).Bind(h)).Sample()`  These workflows are incredibly concise and adaptable.

Comment: "Now suppose we have a question: what is a likely state of an entity after two opportunities?" But I never want to ask this question? You're trying to solve different problems than I have, and all this is irrelevant because the single line question in my title still goes unanswered! You've given 0 reason to ditch a dictionary, all I am doing with the dictionary is turning it into a score, none of this given stuff. You wouldn't even be talking about this stuff if I made it return a long instead of a dictionary which is essentially what it equates to, but didn't because that conversion can...

Comment: ...be stored inside the Entity implementation. If I re-ask this question but replace that Dictionary<IEntity, long> return with just a long, and rename the method to "GetActionScore" which will make 0 functional difference but will hide the probability stuff you won't stop talking about which I have already fully solved in my project and need no help with and actually answer the question I do have?

Comment: @Shefeto: You're not following me here. Your question is how to rearchitect this code because you're having a double dispatch problem. I'm saying that if you structure your workflows using monadic types, *it doesn't matter how you solve your double dispatch problem*; you have the *flexibility* to solve it however you like, and *change* that implementation without modifying the workflow code. The traditional OOP solution would be a visitor pattern, the traditional functional solution would be an external method that can be partially evaluated. Doesn't matter. Get the type algebra right.